# All storyboard, xib file don't update the frame or constraint on Macbook Pro M1 with rosetta (Encountered an error communicating with IBAgent-iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode12, apple-m1

I try to add constraint or load some of the storyboards or XIB files in my project but the storyboard doesn't update and can't see anything.
This is my error screen capture:

[image: In the first picture, the label is shown in the simulator but the storyboard doesn't]

[image: This .xib file can't load any UI items]

In the first picture, the label is shown in the simulator but the storyboard doesn't.

In the second picture, The .xib file can't load any UI items

This is my error log:

> =================================
> DATE:
> =================================
>
> Monday, 21 December 2020 at 14:22:27 Japan Standard Time 2020-12-21
> 05:22:27 +0000
>
> =================================
> XCODE VERSION INFO:
> =================================
>
> Version = 12.3 (12C33) Plugin Version = 17701 Beta Version = 1 OS
> Version = 11.1 (20C69)
>
> =================================
> ERROR:
> =================================
>
> Encountered an error communicating with IBAgent-iOS. (Failure reason:
> IBAgent-iOS (-1) failed to launch): Failed to launch IBAgent-iOS via
> CoreSimulator spawn (Failure reason: Failed to spawn IBAgent-iOS on
> iPhone 12 Pro Max (D81D1F57-170A-4089-843E-1D1E58B049C6, iOS 14.3,
> Booted)): Invalid device state
>
> Error Domain=com.apple.InterfaceBuilder Code=-1 "Encountered an error
> communicating with IBAgent-iOS."
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=IBAgent-iOS (-1) failed to launch,
> NSUnderlyingError=0x7fea6c306aa0 {Error
> Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=405 "Failed to launch
> IBAgent-iOS via CoreSimulator spawn"
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to spawn IBAgent-iOS on
> iPhone 12 Pro Max (D81D1F57-170A-4089-843E-1D1E58B049C6, iOS 14.3,
> Booted), NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to launch IBAgent-iOS via
> CoreSimulator spawn, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fea689e0de0 {Error
> Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=405 "Invalid device
> state" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid device state}}}},
> NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please check Console.app for crash
> reports for "IBAgent-iOS" for further information.,
> NSLocalizedDescription=Encountered an error communicating with
> IBAgent-iOS.}
>
> =================================
> TOOL DESCRIPTION:
> =================================
>
> <IBCocoaTouchPlatformToolDescription: 0x7feaaba355a0> { |
> targetRuntime.identifier: IBCocoaTouchFramework-fourteenAndLater |
> _roleString: System content | deviceTypeDescription: <IBSimulatorDeviceTypeDescription: 0x7fea6a16c000>
> deviceType=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-12-Pro-Max }
>
> =================================
> LAUNCH CONTEXT:
> =================================
>
> <IBCocoaTouchToolLaunchContext: 0x7fea6c3fbbb0> { |
> toolDescription.ib_verboseDescription:
> <IBCocoaTouchPlatformToolDescription: 0x7feaaba355a0> { | |
> targetRuntime.identifier: IBCocoaTouchFramework-fourteenAndLater | |
> _roleString: System content | | deviceTypeDescription: <IBSimulatorDeviceTypeDescription: 0x7fea6a16c000>
> deviceType=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-12-Pro-Max | }
> | launchPath:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Overlays/IBAgent-iOS
> | frameworkSearchPaths: (
> "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks"
> ) | toolName: IBAgent-iOS | platformName: iphonesimulator |
> applicationTool: 0 | processIdentifier: -1 | exitStatus: (null) |
> signalStatus: (null) }
>
> =================================
> EXECUTION CONTEXT:
> =================================
>
> <IBSimulatorToolCoreSimulatorBootedCLIExecutionContext: 0x7fea6c11b010
> busyCount=0, Idle for 0.0 secs> { | device: iPhone 12 Pro Max
> (D81D1F57-170A-4089-843E-1D1E58B049C6, iOS 14.3, Booted) }
>
> =================================
> DEVICE:
> =================================
>
> iPhone 12 Pro Max (D81D1F57-170A-4089-843E-1D1E58B049C6, iOS 14.3,
> Booted)
>
> =================================
> TOOL MANAGER:
> =================================
>
> <IBCocoaTouchToolManager: 0x7fea6a150100>
>
> =================================
> REASON FOR REQUESTING TOOL:
> =================================
>
> Preflighting tools for opening document <IBStoryboardDocument:
> 0x7fea69139a00>: <IBCocoaTouchTargetRuntime: 0x7fea6a1525d0>
>
> =================================
> XCODE BACKTRACE:
> =================================
>
> 0   +[IBPlatformToolFailureHandler
> failureHandlerWithContext:failure:diagnosticsHandlerBlock:] (in
> IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)   1
> +[IBAbstractInterfaceBuilderPlatformToolManager _THREADSAFE_injectDiagnosticsHandlerWithFailureContext:intoError:forLaunchingToolWithError:]
> (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)   2
> +[IBAbstractInterfaceBuilderPlatformToolManager _THREADSAFE_launchNewToolWithLaunchContext:executionContext:toolProxyClass:proxyDelegate:failureContext:requestingMethod:error:forReason:]
> (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)   3
> __117-[IBAbstractInterfaceBuilderPlatformToolManager asyncLaunchNewToolWithDescription:queue:completionHandler:forReason:]_block_invoke.429
> (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)   4   _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in
> libdispatch.dylib)   5   _dispatch_client_callout (in
> libdispatch.dylib)   6   _dispatch_lane_serial_drain (in
> libdispatch.dylib)   7   _dispatch_lane_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
> 8   _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread (in libdispatch.dylib)   9
> _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)  10   start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
>
> =================================
> SDKS:
> =================================
>
> Simulator - watchOS 7.2 (watchsimulator7.2): version = 7.2 platform =
> com.apple.platform.watchsimulator versionInfo = {
> BuildID = "8D9D1CD2-32F3-11EB-B18E-209C67F7BDAB";
> ProductBuildVersion = 18S561;
> ProductCopyright = "1983-2020 Apple Inc.";
> ProductName = "Watch OS";
> ProductVersion = "7.2"; }
>
> Simulator - watchOS 7.2 (watchsimulator7.2): version = 7.2 platform =
> com.apple.platform.watchsimulator versionInfo = {
> BuildID = "8D9D1CD2-32F3-11EB-B18E-209C67F7BDAB";
> ProductBuildVersion = 18S561;
> ProductCopyright = "1983-2020 Apple Inc.";
> ProductName = "Watch OS";
> ProductVersion = "7.2"; }
>
> tvOS 14.3 (appletvos14.3): version = 14.3 platform =
> com.apple.platform.appletvos versionInfo = {
> BuildID = "E3F85AF8-32C4-11EB-9F1B-1F54C5D7F887";
> ProductBuildVersion = 18K559;
> ProductCopyright = "1983-2020 Apple Inc.";
> ProductName = "Apple TVOS";
> ProductVersion = "14.3"; }
>
> Simulator - iOS 14.3 (iphonesimulator14.3): version = 14.3 platform =
> com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator versionInfo = {
> BuildID = "88F866D8-32D9-11EB-997E-99E30E3CEA69";
> ProductBuildVersion = 18C61;
> ProductCopyright = "1983-2020 Apple Inc.";
> ProductName = "iPhone OS";
> ProductVersion = "14.3"; }
>
> Simulator - tvOS 14.3 (appletvsimulator14.3): version = 14.3 platform
> = com.apple.platform.appletvsimulator versionInfo = {
> BuildID = "E3F85AF8-32C4-11EB-9F1B-1F54C5D7F887";
> ProductBuildVersion = 18K559;
> ProductCopyright = "1983-2020 Apple Inc.";
> ProductName = "Apple TVOS";
> ProductVersion = "14.3"; }
>
> watchOS 7.2 (watchos7.2): version = 7.2 platform =
> com.apple.platform.watchos versionInfo = {
> BuildID = "8D9D1CD2-32F3-11EB-B18E-209C67F7BDAB";
> ProductBuildVersion = 18S561;
> ProductCopyright = "1983-2020 Apple Inc.";
> ProductName = "Watch OS";
> ProductVersion = "7.2"; }
>
> Simulator - tvOS 14.3 (appletvsimulator14.3): version = 14.3 platform
> = com.apple.platform.appletvsimulator versionInfo = {
> BuildID = "E3F85AF8-32C4-11EB-9F1B-1F54C5D7F887";
> ProductBuildVersion = 18K559;
> ProductCopyright = "1983-2020 Apple Inc.";
> ProductName = "Apple TVOS";
> ProductVersion = "14.3"; }
>
> macOS 11.1 (macosx11.1): version = 11.1 platform =
> com.apple.platform.macosx versionInfo = {
> ProductBuildVersion = 20C63;
> ProductCopyright = "1983-2020 Apple Inc.";
> ProductName = macOS;
> ProductUserVisibleVersion = "11.1";
> ProductVersion = "11.1";
> iOSSupportVersion = "14.3"; }
>
> iOS 14.3 (iphoneos14.3): version = 14.3 platform =
> com.apple.platform.iphoneos versionInfo = {
> BuildID = "88F866D8-32D9-11EB-997E-99E30E3CEA69";
> ProductBuildVersion = 18C61;
> ProductCopyright = "1983-2020 Apple Inc.";
> ProductName = "iPhone OS";
> ProductVersion = "14.3"; }
>
> watchOS 7.2 (watchos7.2): version = 7.2 platform =
> com.apple.platform.watchos versionInfo = {
> BuildID = "8D9D1CD2-32F3-11EB-B18E-209C67F7BDAB";
> ProductBuildVersion = 18S561;
> ProductCopyright = "1983-2020 Apple Inc.";
> ProductName = "Watch OS";
> ProductVersion = "7.2"; }
>
> iOS 14.3 (iphoneos14.3): version = 14.3 platform =
> com.apple.platform.iphoneos versionInfo = {
> BuildID = "88F866D8-32D9-11EB-997E-99E30E3CEA69";
> ProductBuildVersion = 18C61;
> ProductCopyright = "1983-2020 Apple Inc.";
> ProductName = "iPhone OS";
> ProductVersion = "14.3"; }
>
> macOS 11.1 (macosx11.1): version = 11.1 platform =
> com.apple.platform.macosx versionInfo = {
> ProductBuildVersion = 20C63;
> ProductCopyright = "1983-2020 Apple Inc.";
> ProductName = macOS;
> ProductUserVisibleVersion = "11.1";
> ProductVersion = "11.1";
> iOSSupportVersion = "14.3"; }
>
> tvOS 14.3 (appletvos14.3): version = 14.3 platform =
> com.apple.platform.appletvos versionInfo = {
> BuildID = "E3F85AF8-32C4-11EB-9F1B-1F54C5D7F887";
> ProductBuildVersion = 18K559;
> ProductCopyright = "1983-2020 Apple Inc.";
> ProductName = "Apple TVOS";
> ProductVersion = "14.3"; }
>
> Simulator - iOS 14.3 (iphonesimulator14.3): version = 14.3 platform =
> com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator versionInfo = {
> BuildID = "88F866D8-32D9-11EB-997E-99E30E3CEA69";
> ProductBuildVersion = 18C61;
> ProductCopyright = "1983-2020 Apple Inc.";
> ProductName = "iPhone OS";
> ProductVersion = "14.3"; }
>
> DriverKit 20.2 (driverkit.macosx20.2): version = 20.2 platform =
> com.apple.platform.macosx versionInfo = { }

Please help me.

Comment: If the problem persists, please add Xcode, OS and used xcode commandline tools version.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am also facing the same issue.. but I have to use rosetta for some reason.

Comment: I have the same issue, I am running Xcode using rosetta, because of a pod that is not compiled for arm64 simulator.

Comment: did you resolve this issue?

Comment: fixed this by not using Rosetta. @PhucDang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by not using Rosetta.

[image]

Comment: This does not help if you need to open in Rosetta for some other reason.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. I hope this will be fixed in next xcode release.

Comment: this is my work around too -- works for me so far but it sucks to switching back and front to using rosetta

Answer (score 3):

Not using Rosetta. It worked for me. But the Cocoapods need to use Rosetta on Macbook Pro M1. This drives me crazy. Hope this will be fixed in next Xcode release.

Answer (score 2):

To solve the problem on Apple Silicon:

1. With Rosetta enabled, just add arm64 in the excluded architectures on any iOS Simulator SDK in Build Setting section and build the project.
2. Then close Xcode, disable Rosetta and re-open Xcode. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Please relaunch Xcode and clean build everything. It worked for me.

Comment: Can you tell more detail about the way you clean? @Muskan Arora

Comment: Menu Bar → Product → Clean Build or you can use the shortcut Command+Shift+K

Answer (score 0):

Close the simulator app.

Restart xcode.

Run.

If the problem persists, "erase content and settings" on the used sim.

Make sure the latest Xcode version is installed. Make sure the version of the used command line tools fits the used X code version (Xcode preferences).